# Simple server in c++ . Freeaddinfo (Segmenataion fault) MSDN Example

Tags: c++, server

I'm new in Server Development. And sry for newbee questions and for my bad english . 
I'm try to create a simple server based MSDN Example.I do not know where else I can get information about the ms socket. This is my code

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define DEFAULT_PORT "2343"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int main() {

char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult, iSendResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

struct addrinfo *result = nullptr, *ptr = nullptr, hints;

WSADATA wsaData;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsaData);
if (iResult != 0 ){
    std:: cout << "WSAStartup failed: \n" << iResult;
    return 1;
}

memset(&hints, 0 , sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol  = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;


iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL,DEFAULT_PORT,&hints,&result);
if(iResult !=0){
    std:: cout << "getaddrinfo failed: \n" << iResult;
    //WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}


SOCKET ListenSock = INVALID_SOCKET;


ListenSock = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

if(ListenSock = INVALID_SOCKET){
    std:: cout << "Error at socket \n" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    //WSACleanup();
}

iResult = bind(ListenSock,result -> ai_addr, (int)result -> ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
    std:: cout << "bind failed \n" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

//I got a error : Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) - here 

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSock);
    //WSACleanup();
}
freeaddrinfo(result);
```

Idk how fix it, if you can help me, thank you very much .

Comment: Use a debugger. Exit or return on failure.

Comment: Yep . Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ListenSock = INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Should be:

```
if(ListenSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

Comment: wow. Oh my god :D Sry. I saw a clue in my IDE but..idk why i dont do it :D Thank you very much